# Combinning dataframes with datetime and pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, datetime, time

The code down below reads the 2 csv files down below and then turns the `date\Date` to `pd.to_datetime()`, to combine them together with the `data_combo` function. However the `pd.to_datetime()` function `date` does not work the `type` for the `data` remains to be `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>` but it is supposed to be `<class 'pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex'>` how can I do the necessary conversion so that the expected output is achieved?

Code:

```
import functools
import pandas as pd 
import datetime

def datetime_convert(dataset):
    data =pd.read_csv(dataset[0], low_memory=False)
    #reverses all the table data values 
    data1 = data.iloc[::-1].reset_index(drop=True)
    dataset = data1[dataset[1]]
    date = pd.to_datetime(dataset)
    return date

data1= datetime_convert(['data1.csv', 'date'])
data2 = datetime_convert(['data2', 'Date'])

data_combo = functools.reduce(pd.Index.union, [data1, data2])
```

data1 csv:

```
Unix Timestamp  date                    Symbol  
1444311600      2015-10-08 13:40:00     BTCUSD
1444311660      2015-10-08 13:41:00     BTCUSD
1444311720      2015-10-08 13:42:00     BTCUSD
```

data2 csv:

```
Unix Timestamp  Date                    Symbol  
1634774460000   2021-10-21 00:01:00     BTCUSD
1634774520000   2021-10-21 00:02:00     BTCUSD
1634774580000   2021-10-21 00:03:00     BTCUSD
```

Expected output:

```
DatetimeIndex([[2015-10-08 13:40:00, 2015-10-08 13:41:00, 2015-10-08 13:42:00, 
2021-10-21 00:01:00, 2021-10-21 00:02:00, 2021-10-21 00:03:00],dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Comment: Are you saying that both `data1` and `data2` are `pandas.Series`?

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you 1st change name of date header to Date then
Try convert both to datetime then merge these 2 dataframes.
And  set Date Column as index

I cannot comment so am writing here

Comment: Yea I have manually changed the column names to 'date' on the csvs but I cannot change them to `datetime` with `pd.to_datetime()`

Comment: from datetime import datetime
dateparse = lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

df = pd.read_csv(infile, parse_dates=['date'], date_parser=dateparse) try this